# Using backreference wit php preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, backreference

I'am quite new in regex and php but I'm facing an issue I can't handle alone.

I've prepared this regex to find patterns starting with upper-case letter. It could sounds something like :

- capture any pattern that
- starts with one or more Upper-case letter
- then one or more any letter or character in the list
- then a space, or punctuation mark
- and I use a backreference to set I want those pattern up to 3 times  :

  ```
  ([A-ZÁÀÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÔÖÚÙÛÜ]{1,}[a-zàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ;:«0-9]{1,}[\s-….?,;]\1{1,3})
  ```

According to https://regex101.com/r/pB3nY7/2 it works as a javascript regex but not as a php regex.

I've rade the other posts and make sure :

- I use single quotes instead of double quotes
- and I "protected" the \ in my php script :

  ```
  '#([A-ZÁÀÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÔÖÚÙÛÜ]{1,}[a-zàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ;:«0-9]{1,}[\\s-….?,;]\\1{1,3})#'
  ```

But it still can't match any pattern starting with a Upper-case letter.

Thank you in advance for all advice you may provide,

Regards,

Charles

Comment: In PCRE, `\1` inside Group  1 is still not initialized, thus it fails. JS behaves differently, `\1` is always an empty string if it is not initialized. I think you do not need the `\1` at all here. See [`([A-ZÁÀÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÔÖÚÙÛÜ]{1,}[a-zàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ;:«0-9]{1,}[\s-….?,;]{1,3})`](https://regex101.com/r/dT1gQ3/1) demo. Doesn't it match what you need?

Comment: Thank you Wiktor.
I wanted to take the opportunity of this regex to learn how backreference are working, but your solution is easier.
Thanks

Comment: Shall I post as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

i have tested it on this website http://www.phpliveregex.com/ :

```
(^[A-ZÁÀÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÔÖÚÙÛÜ]{1,}[a-zàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ;:«0-9]{1,}[\s-….?,;]{1,1}){1,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more generalist, you could use unicode properties:

```
^(\p[Lu}+[\p{Ll};:«0-9]+[\s\p{P}]){1,3}
```

Where `\p[Lu}` stands for an uppercase letter, `\p{Ll}` a lowercase letter and `\p{P}` a punctuation.

```
preg_match('/^(\p[Lu}+[\p{Ll};:«0-9]+[\s\p{P}]){1,3}/', $string, $match);
```

Comment: Thanks Toto, 
I do not know so much things about regex nore unicode properties. Does it works with accented characters ?

Comment: @Charles: Yes it does. It works for any letter in any language. It contains also some letters with diacritic you have missed `ÇŒœ...`. You will find informations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property and http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt